# Failed to Publish Web Layer/Service, Staging Error

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-server, web-service, arcgis-portal, publishing

Running into an error when publishing a service and web layer to AGS/portal.  After finding as many troubleshooting tips that I can, I am still running into errors.

First off, Loading a basemap from the same portal results in an ! about layer not compatible with server and clashing with projections, the rest of the ! are about the data not being registered to the data store.  Mind you, these errors can be ignored, and have been ignored in the past and have published fine.  I gave up on registering data to data store, because regardless of registering my Folder, my Database, or saving the FCs into an already registered data store, I still get those errors.

Here is what I have made sure are not issues:

- No invalid characters in file names, in contents page, and in attribution headers
- Location URL is not longer than 82 characters
- All data is stored in the same fGDB
- All data is of the same projection
- Is not special data, I am using regular, new FCs as tests with little to no attribution

I have had mixed results.  Some times it will fail entirely, other times it will say staging failed BUT still post as a web layer and service. When this occurs, it can load into ArcGIS Pro, but not other programs, regardless if I use WMSServer, MapServer, or ArcGIS Server links. The program will say failed to load core layer. When it does publish it lists its location as in server its listed as F:\xxx\xxxxxxxxx\xxx.aprx

I have used more mixed data, had more layers, more errors, and same basemaps in the past, and not had this issue.  I am now at a loss of what to try next.